# expressjs / nodejs general routes conflicting with wildcard

Tags: node.js, express

```html
full code looks like this

  /* /login [get] */
  app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login');
          return;
  });


 app.get('/stats', requireLogin, function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ _id: req.user.id})
  .populate('current')
  .exec(function(err, stats) {
   if (err) res.json(err)
   res.render('stats', stats);
   return;
  })
 });
  /* /username */
  app.get('/:username', requireLogin, function(req, res) {
   console.log("sdf");
   User
   .findOne({ username: req.params.username }, 'friends')
   .exec(function(err, user) {
    console.log(user)
   })
      
going to /login  renders the login page, but also triggers the console.log of "sdf from the next route
```

In my app, one can access /someusername

I have that route defined as

```html
app.get('/:username', function(req, res) {
```

but because I also have these general ones like /stats and /login

```
app.get('/stats', function(req, res) {})
app.get('login',  function(req, res) {})
```

going to these also accesses the /:username route.

how do I prevent that?

(the /:username route is the last one in the code)

Comment: Why cant you add some context before the route? Like `/user/:username` ?

Comment: I want it to act just like every other major social network

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Routes are processed by Express in order.  So, if you put the `/stats` route before the `/:username` route and you don't manually force routing to continue further by calling `next()`, then things will work for you.  The more specific route will be found and processed first.

But, this is probably a bad URL design when you have conflicting URLs.  What if a user was named `"stats`", then their username URL would never work.  And, what if you then want some other URL such as `/login` or `/about`.  All of those would conflict with potential user names.  That's just a bad design.

Probably, you should change to something like this:

```
app.get('/user/:username', function(req, res) {...}
```

So, no user name route can ever conflict with your `/stats` route or any other top level route you choose.  This will keep your top level path available to direct routes into categories and would be a much better URL design.

---

And, as we discovered in further discussion, the browser requesting the favicon for the page will also hit your `/:username` route.  You can make a special route for the favicon or you can insert meta tags in the page to prevent a favicon request or you can stop using a top level wildcard route that catches these types of things.  Note, you'll probably also catch things like when bots request `/robots.txt` too.

Comment: all the general routes are actually before the /:username route

Comment: @totalnoob - Then, show us the actual code in order, including the route handlers because if that's actually the case, then you are doing something else wrong that you are not showing us (like calling `next()` to keep the route processing going when you shouldn't be).

Comment: @totalnoob - I suspect you are seeing a 2nd browser request for the page icon and that is going to your `/:username` route.  This is yet another reason why a catch all route handler at the top level path is a bad design.  This would probably also happen when bots look for `/robots.txt`.  You can confirm this by logging `req.originalUrl` in your `/:username` route and/or by looking at the network tab in the Chrome debugger in the browser to see which requests are being sent.

Comment: I added a catch for the favicon and no longer seeing the problem. I will take your suggestion into account. thanks for figuring this out!

Answer (score 1):

> (the /:username route is the last one in the code)

**It should work if you have put username route at last of all the other routes.**

If you want username route to be at top,you can validate in the /:username route , but **it is not recommended and bad design**.

```
var reseredKeywords = ['stats', 'login'];
app.get('/:username', function(req, res, next) {
  if (reseredKeywords.indexOf(req.param.username.toLowerCase())) {
    next();
  }
  // else handle your username here
})
```

Comment: This is really not a good overall design.  The URL design is just flawed because every top level path component you might ever want to use in a URL potentially conflicts with usernames.  The URL design should be changed and fixed so these conflicts do not exist.

Comment: @jfriend00, how does Twitter and Facebook deal with it?

Comment: @totalnoob You dont have username as `settings` or `groups` in facebook. You have to provide first name and lastname. You profile will be something as `facebook.com/<firstname>.<lastname>` etc

Comment: @totalnoob - Facebook created a mess where they are restricted on what top level path items they can use in their URLs.  Do not copy that.  Just because someone else does it one way does not mean it's a good design for what you're doing.  If you want to predetermine, in advance, all top level path elements you will EVER want to use in your URLs and then block any user name from ever being created that conflict and once a username is created, you can never ever use that as a top level path element, then go right ahead, but it's a brittle design in my opinion and I would never recommmend it.

Comment: @jfriend00 `Facebook created a mess ... URLs` .. can you share link regarding this... I guess it would be interesting read

Comment: I'm just saying that using `http://example.com/username` creates a hard to maintain mess because all possible top level path names you might want to use in your URL design potentially conflict with a username.  Designing a conflict like this is not a good starting point for a URL design.  It forces you very carefully reserve in advance any top level path name you will EVER want to use so it isn't accidentally used by some user.